# P/Invoke and NativeMethods convention for enums/structs

Tags: c#, enums, pinvoke

When doing pinvokes, the convention is to put them inside a NativeMethods class but, bearing in mind that neither enums nor structs need to be inside a class, what is the convention for enums and structs that are used by the pinvoke?

Is it to also have them inside the NativeMethods class, on a separate class, no class at all?

I suppose same could be said for consts used by the pinvoke, is the convention also to have them inside the NativeMethods class?

Also, what is the convention for naming structs, enums and consts used by pinvoke functions? In C++ they'll be defined as something like `CREATE_VIRTUAL_DISK_VERSION`, is the convention to keep it exactly as is or to convert them to the C# standard, which in this case would make it `CreateVirtualDiskVersion`?

**EDIT**

For a clearer example, let's the following struct, as defined in MSDN and used by the native function `ExpandVirtualDisk`:

```
typedef struct _EXPAND_VIRTUAL_DISK_PARAMETERS {
  EXPAND_VIRTUAL_DISK_VERSION Version;
  union {
    struct {
      ULONGLONG NewSize;
    } Version1;
  };
} EXPAND_VIRTUAL_DISK_PARAMETERS, *PEXPAND_VIRTUAL_DISK_PARAMETERS;
```

When declaring this in C# so that it can be passed as a param to the `ExpandVirtualDisk` native function, would you declare it as...

```
public struct EXPAND_VIRTUAL_DISK_PARAMETERS
{
    public EXPAND_VIRTUAL_DISK_VERSION Version;
    (...)
}
```

or something like...

```
public struct ExpandVirtualDiskParameters
{
    public ExpandVirtualDiskVersion Version;
    (...)
}
```

And would you place it inside the `NativeMethods` class?

Comment: Standard?  Don't know.  But I prefer to keep it all together in `NativeMethods`.  As for naming, I preserve the C++ naming to keep it recognizable against the native code being targeted.

Comment: @usr I have a feeling you might have misunderstood me. Have a look at my edit for clarification please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That pinvoke declarations should be in a Un/SafeNativeMethods class is a coding guideline for Microsoft programmers.  Unfortunately that rule leaked out when they also published the tool they used to enforce the coding guidelines, formerly named FxCop.

It makes *some* sense to do so when you work for Microsoft on the base assemblies, it reduces the odds that declarations get duplicated and a pinvoke declaration is likely to be used multiple times in different classes.  The .NET framework assemblies have a lot of pinvoke code.  Forcing the Microsoft programmer to think about safety is also quite important.  They however still get duplicated, different base assemblies each have their own set of pinvoke declarations and they often disagree with each other.  In naming and also the safe/unsafe choice.  Not very pretty but the somewhat inevitable side-effect of having different teams work on different parts of the framework.

Those same rules just don't apply to mere mortals like us.  Pinvoke should be avoided as much as possible.  A good scope for any declaration is `private`, an implementation detail that is hidden as well as possible and preferably as close as possible to the code that uses it.  But if you like to use Code Analysis and don't want to maintain your own ruleset then you are pretty much forced to do it Microsoft's way.

The most sane way to go about it is to adopt your team's coding guidelines and have a matching ruleset to enforce it.  At which point you can do anything you want and is agreed upon by the team.  Much the same applies to identifier name-casing.  I *personally* always copy/paste from the SDK header file, the best way to avoid very hard to diagnose mistakes.  And have never found a good reason to rename the identifier, the compiler does not care and that the declaration is fundamentally different from a normal one gives me a good reason to keep it looking different as well.  But that's just my personal preference, I can't help you decide on your own.